# Libgdx Box2D - Linear Velocity Drops While Body Falls Down

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

First off, let me say that I'm just beginning to explore the world of Box2D and LibGDX.
So, if anything I'm doing/asking is very rookie'ish ... Well - now you know why!

I'm trying to create a Box2d World with with a falling body (dynamic) that lands on the ground (static)

- World has a gravity of -9.8f.
- The ground has 0.0f friction
- The falling body has 0.0f angular velocity, angular damping and linear damping.
- The falling body has a starting linear velocity of 20.0f

The oddball "issue" I'm noticing is that as the body falls down, it looses linear velocity.

The higher the starting point for the player - the lower his linear velocity by the time he gets to the ground.

This is the code I'm using.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public class TestGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private int GAME_WIDTH = 1024 ;
    private int GAME_HEIGHT = 768 ;


    Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
    World world ;

    BodyDef bdefPlayer;
    FixtureDef fdefPlayer;
    PolygonShape shapePlayer;
    Body fallingObject;
    int fallingObjectHeight = 64;
    int fallingObjectWidth = 64;

    BodyDef bdefGround;
    FixtureDef fdefGround;
    PolygonShape shapeGround;
    int numberOfGroundUnitsToCreate = 100;
    int groundUnitHeight = 64;
    int groundUnitWidth = 64;
    Body groundUnitsList[] = new Body[numberOfGroundUnitsToCreate];

    boolean isDebugMode = true;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);

        // Create World
        world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, -9.8f), false);

        // Create debug render
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        // Initiate camera
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        camera.setToOrtho(false);
        camera.position.set(GAME_WIDTH/2, GAME_HEIGHT/2, 0);

        // Create Player
        createPlayer();

        // Create Ground
        createGround();

    }

    public void render() {              
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Setup camera to follow Player
        camera.position.x = fallingObject.getPosition().x + 50; 
        camera.update();    

        // Update and render the world
        world.step(1/12f, 6, 2);
        if(isDebugMode) {
            renderer.render(world, camera.combined);            
        }

        System.out.println(
                            "Linear Velocity: " + fallingObject.getLinearVelocity() +
                            " Linear Damping: " + fallingObject.getLinearDamping() +
                            " Angular Velocity: " + fallingObject.getAngularVelocity() +
                            " Angular Damping: " + fallingObject.getAngularDamping() +
                            " World Gravity: " + world.getGravity() +
                            " Density: " + fallingObject.getMass() 
                          );

        handleInput();
    }

    private void createPlayer() { 
        bdefPlayer = new BodyDef();
        fdefPlayer = new FixtureDef();
        shapePlayer = new PolygonShape();

        // create player
        bdefPlayer.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdefPlayer.linearVelocity.x = 20.0f;
        bdefPlayer.linearDamping = 0.00f;
        bdefPlayer.angularDamping = 0.0f;
        bdefPlayer.angularVelocity = 0.0f;
        bdefPlayer.position.set(50,  250);
        fallingObject = world.createBody(bdefPlayer);

        shapePlayer.setAsBox(fallingObjectHeight/2 , fallingObjectWidth/2);
        fdefPlayer.shape = shapePlayer;
        fallingObject.createFixture(fdefPlayer);

        // create foot sensor
        shapePlayer.setAsBox(fallingObjectWidth/2 , 10); 
        fdefPlayer.shape = shapePlayer;
        fdefPlayer.isSensor = true;
        fallingObject.createFixture(fdefPlayer);
    }

    private void createGround() {
        bdefGround = new BodyDef();
        fdefGround = new FixtureDef();
        shapeGround = new PolygonShape();

        for (int i=0; i<numberOfGroundUnitsToCreate; i++) {
            bdefGround.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdefGround.position.set((float) ((groundUnitWidth + 0.5) *i )  , 0);
            shapeGround.setAsBox(groundUnitWidth/2 , groundUnitHeight/2);
            fdefGround.shape = shapeGround;
            fdefGround.friction = 0.0f;
            Body grassTileBodyTemp = world.createBody(bdefGround);
            grassTileBodyTemp.createFixture(fdefGround);

            groundUnitsList[i]= grassTileBodyTemp;
        }
    }

    public void handleInput() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)) 
            fallingObject.applyForceToCenter(0, 20.0f, true);

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) 
            fallingObject.applyForceToCenter(20.0f, 0, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I'm at wits ends on what I'm missing that may be causing this issue.

Comment: When you say "loses linear velocity", what do you mean?  The linear velocity has two components, x and y.  Gravity is pointing in the direction of "-y", but your initial velocity is pointing in "+x".  If you were to print out (x,y) as the body moves, with a solid ground plane, I would expect you to see x unchanged AND y decreasing (getting more negative) as it hurtles towards the ground, then suddenly go to (0,0) over a few time steps as it hits the ground.  Print out the velocity vector...is this what you see?

Comment: Can you show the output of your System.out.println(...)?  I did this "box drop" experiment in cocos2d/box2d (same physics engine) and it worked as expected...

Comment: I couldn't paste the log content to SO because of length restrictions. So, I've uploaded the S.O.P output to DropBox - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rani7e6xy52c9c/Sample_Run_SO_22799601.txt

Do let me know if you have any further questions.

I'm using libgdx 0.9.9 (stable) in my project.

Comment: I did some more testing and here's my findings:

As the body falls, it accelerates dues to gravity.When the vertical velocity approaches 2 times the worlds time_step value, this is when the linear velocity starts going crazy.
Also, another thing I've noticed is when the above said behavior starts - linear velocity behaves in a "haphazard" fashion - i.e Sometimes it decreases rapidly and Sometimes it goes straight to zero.

If I increased the time step to a large value (like 100) - the world updates rather slowly, but the linear velocity issue seems to be addressed.
Is this a libgdx/box2d bug?

Comment: See the first item at https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas Box2D is supposed to clamp the velocity to a maximum value, not make it zero like in your output log, I wonder if that is a problem with libGDX...?

Comment: Finally managed to fix the problem!!!

Here's what I had to do to resolve it:

(Step 1) Scale down world and entities in it to 1/40 - to be compliant with the box2d world dimensions compliant.
(Step 2) Change the ground entities to use ChainShapes instead of polygon shapes - to avoid "Ghost Vertices" issues.

Once I did this, things started working as expected.

Thanks a ton for all your help and support ... I really really reaaaaaaaaaaaaally appreciate it!  :)